# Advantages of using active inductors in ICs

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, integrated-circuit, circuit-design, circuits

I have seen that there exist many methods to realize equivalent inductors in IC through  active components. For instance, through [gyrators](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Op-Amp_Gyrator.svg) realized with Op-Amp.

This solution will require a lot of transistors. Which is the advantages of choosing it, and not a proper inductor? I know that in ICs it is very difficult to realize inductors with L greater than 20nH because of the lack of space in the substrate, while transistors are little, with lower parasitics and their realization pattern is "standardized". But I'd say it is convenient only if it allows to get high values of L, in general L>>20nH. Which is a typical value?

Comment: _"I know that in ICs it is very difficult to realize inductors with L greater than 20nH because of the lack of space in the substrate, while transistors are little, with lower parasitics and their realization pattern is "standardized""_ - there's your answer. Can you provide any examples of ICs that use gyrators in place of inductors?

Comment: Just look at the wiki on the topic: "Simulated inductors do not have the inherent energy storing properties of the real inductors and this limits the possible power applications." Don't ask here. Go do some study, first.

Comment: @jonk my question is about the ADVANTAGE of using simulated inductors, not their limits. Moderate the tones. We all have to learn, you included.

Comment: @Bruce Abbott I have not found a real example. I have only read it in some books about filter design in ICs

Comment: @Kinka-Byo Cool. Then have at it. There are plenty of folks here much better than I at this question. Best wishes. And maybe I'll learn from you.

Comment: @Kinka-Byo Your question really felt to me as though you had not appreciated some of the details on the Wiki page. Had you, you would have written differently. I concluded that you should do your due diligence and come back, later. Your follow-up reply to me was in part fairly made and no offense was taken from it. But it also left me with no interest in helping and breaking company seemed best. But I could write quite a bit on three or four practical application spaces with schematics and bode plots, so you'd see the important (admittedly limited in many ways) niches where these well apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name gyrator is just a convenient term for an electronic circuit that replaces the functionality of a grounded inductor. There may be circuits called gyrators that can replace the functionality of a series inductor but these are much rarer and are probably explained away using conventional filter explanations anyway.

> Which is a typical value?

But, if you want a really common example of a circuit that somewhat mimics an inductor, try thinking about a constant current source or sink. It mimics an inductor value of infinite henries and they are used all over the place, inside and outside analogue chips.